# AngularJs UI router URL formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [angularjs-ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) module for managing my states.

I have this structure:

```
$stateProvider.state('menu', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/menu/wrap.html',
        params: {
            slug: {
                value: ''
            },
            id: {
                value: null
            }
        },
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Menu'
        }

    }).state('menu.list', {
        url: '/:slug',
        parent: 'menu',
        params: {
            slug: {
                value: ''
            },
            id: {
                value: null
            },
            Name: {
                value: '{{Name}}'
            },
            Type: {
                value: null
            }
        },

        views: {
            // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/menu/main.html',
                controller: 'MenuMainCtrl as MNC'
            },

            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
            'productList@menu.list': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/menu/productlist.html',
                controller: 'ProductListCtrl as PLC'
            },
            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
            'navigation@menu.list': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/menu/navigation.html',
                controller: 'MenuNavigationCtrl as MN'
            },
            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
            'cart@menu.list': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/menu/cart.html',
                controller: 'CartCtrl as CC'
            }
        },
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: '{{Name}}'
        }
    }).state('menu.detail', {
            parent: 'menu.list',
            url: '/:productSlug',
            params: {
                productID: {
                    value: ""
                },
                productSlug: {
                    value: ""
                },
                productName: {
                    value: ""
                },
                Name: {
                    value: "Breakfast"
                },
                Type: {
                    value: null
                },
                MenuListItemID: {
                    value: null
                }

            },
            views: {
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/menu/productSingle.html',
                    controller: 'ProductSingleCtrl as PSC'
                }
            },

            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: '{{productName}}'
            }

        });
```

See the last state named "menu.detail". Base URL for this is "/menu/" and when this state is active my URL is eg. "localhost:8081/menu/breakfast-sandwiches/farmtotable-breakfast-sandwiches" but my client would like to be "localhost:8081/product/farmtotable-breakfast-sandwiches".

Is this even possible and if is, can You help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the parent URL the following way:

```
.state('menu.detail', {
    parent: 'menu.list',
    url: '^/product/:productSlug',
    params: {
        productID: {
            value: ""
        },
        productSlug: {
            value: ""
        },
        productName: {
            value: ""
        },
        Name: {
            value: "Breakfast"
        },
        Type: {
            value: null
        },
        MenuListItemID: {
            value: null
        }

    },
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: '/templates/menu/productSingle.html',
            controller: 'ProductSingleCtrl as PSC'
        }
    },

    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: '{{productName}}'
    }

});
```

Comment: I updated "url" key and now state is still working but URL is "localhost:8080/menu/product/classic-lunch-signature". See this "/menu/" I would like to get rid of that and url to be "localhost:8080/product/classic-lunch-signature" @abhim

Comment: I made it to work. I just changed my "<base href="/menu/">" to "<base href="/">" and with a little tweeks it's working like a charm.